# What are all the scenarios where server will/can challenge with 401 Unauthorized again for an existing verified account?

Tags: sip, unauthorized

What are the scenarios where server will/can challenge with 401 Unauthorized again for an existing verified account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all up to server, but particular implementation may e.g. put time limit for nonce lifespan or release old nonce to free some memory or encode timestamp inside nonce thus requiring to change it every hour or so. Server or part of it can also be restarted losing info on nonces used earlier. It may also don't use nonce counters at all and issue new nonce with every received request. Tracking nonce counters across multiple transaction may also fail and server may decide to change nonce for safety.

Comment: ok..thanks..but is there any way to get to know what is the timelimit for nonce has been set? I am getting 'stale' header as 'false' in my case.

Comment: I don't think there is any reliable method of testing it. What looks like time limit may be random as well. You should rather look into registrar server code.